# Security of string resources

Tags: iphone, objective-c, security

Recently i've [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707744/security-of-string-resources) about the security implications of storing sensitive info in the xml string resources in Android: the answer? Heavy security implications, is really easy to get the contents of every xml file with a simple command line tool, so it is almost mandatory to have important info encrypted.

Now, how is it like in iOS? How secure it is to have a certain data in a plist or a .strings localizable file, in plain text, non encrypted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still not very secure.

There is nothing stopping a user from unzipping an application stored on their computer in iTunes and viewing the contents. Its very easy to do, even without a jail broken phone. Any strings resources, plist files etc will be immediately accessible.

Even hard coded string literals are visible in the compiled binary when one views it with the `strings` utility. And going a set further, using the `nm` utility one can see all your applications symbols, such as method names, constants, etc.

I would recommend against storing anything that could be considered sensitive in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You can access any file on a jailbroken iPhone, so you'll need to encrypt sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

The exact same problems, a plist is a very common file for Mac OSX and iOS and it is just a XML file. Secure your sensitive data on **ALL** platforms!

I would like to add that apple does provide a way to securely store sensitive information in the [Keychain](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your app ships with a .plist file, then the end user can unzip the .ipa app file and see the .plist file and do whatever they want with it.