# License Check question in Android

Tags: android, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Licensing Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671722/android-licensing-problem)

I am using the License service which I got from here (http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html). However, many hackers can still crack this, I wonder if I put the License code in all of my activities, can the hackers still hack my app? I am also interested to know how they disable the License checkers, thanks in advance!

Comment: @user709028: Being rude to people will make it harder for you to get help here; no one wants to spend their time only to be insulted afterwward. If you haven't already, you should read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), particularly the part about how you should behave towards others. The community here works on respect for each other; if that's difficult for you, perhaps you should be looking for help somewhere less interactive like google. Thanks in advance for your cooperation.

Comment: @user709028: Going around posting obscenities and nonsense on posts will get your account flagged. You're not helping yourself get help by acting like a child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling can be done only if the device has been rooted by using the terminal anyone can disable any activity of any application :).