# App Licensing to one time paid apps

Tags: android, google-play

I'm in final stage of my project, and I was looking for what to do before publish the app then I came across this App Licensing on [https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html](http://Licensing) and this quote

> The Google Play Licensing service is primarily intended for paid
>   applications that wish to verify that the current user did in fact pay
>   for the application on Google Play.

My app has a free version and a pro version, both have a different package name, the user buy the pro version and after that have anything more to buy (no itens inside to buy).

- My doubt is should I implement this Licensing, or it is no needed?
- The google play already do this control to not allow that other people can download of .apk and use this pro version without pay for it?
- And what I have to do to do the Android on user device delete the .apk and this way avoid that the user give the .apk of pro version to someone else? Has any code that I can implement to do that? Or Google Play take care of it?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you should use Google LVL service and the LVL service technically takes care of all your concerns.

Comment: @Hardtack But the Google Play do not control that? I mean it does not prevent that someone that have not paid can do the download? So, for what I have to implement LVL? And my doubt about .apk is because anyone with root access can easily copy the .apk, so, the own Google Play will already delete it, or should I implement something? Thanks

Comment: With LVL, someone cannot download paid app without paying it. Copied apk cannot be used without checking with LVL. But LVL can be cracked. I don't know Android deletes apk after installing an app. Please read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10033081/7303462